# (Answered) How to write to a specific line in a JSON file with Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm looking to create a method that gets passed a line number and some text and then saves that text on the specific line number in a json file (overwriting anything already there, or simply deleting the content there before the new text is written, same effect).

Then a second method that gets passed just a line number and returns whatever is written on that line.

I'm using Typescript and Playwright right now and have done anything like this before but after googling around I haven't managed to find the answer I'm looking for so thought I'd ask you fine folk for help as well.

Not sure where to start. Most tutorials I can find for this sort of thing online are for Python and when I find one for Typescript it never mentions the ability to read/write based on line number.

Thanks in advance, let me know if there's any other details I can provide to give more context.

Alternatively, if this isn't really possible or effective, let me describe what I'm trying to do in detail. I'm working on writing automated UI tests for insurance quotes. I need one set of tests to make quotes and a second set of tests to open those quotes and do some other stuff with them at a later date (namely after a big deployment). So I'm looking to have the first set of tests save their reference numbers to a json file, so the second set of tests can fetch those reference numbers from that file and know which quotes to open on the UI. This test suite will cover 29 different products though so my idea was that the first test that makes the quote will save it's reference number to line 1 of the JSON then the first test that interacts with the quotes later would be for the same product and would fetch line 1 of the JSON to get the reference number it needs, then repeat for all 28 other products after that. But I'm new to this type of thing entirely so if my idea isn't the best way to accomplish this then I am all ears for a better or easier solution. Thanks

Edit: Looks like parsing and stringfying the JSON solves my issue and I was just overthinking it. Thank you @Dimava for the suggestion.

Comment: The **stupid** (straightforward, enough in most cases) way you probably should use is `JSON.parse`ing the file and `JSON.stringify`ing it back. But it breaks formatting if it's not formatted if you didn't use `JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}, null, '  ')` or slike to make it

Comment: Otherwise, `lines = fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8').split('\n') ; lines[123] = 'foo', fs.writeFile(lines.join('\n'))`

Comment: @Dimava thanks for your answer, I found a tutorial going over similar things using nodejs but I thought it wouldn't apply to me because I wanted the line number solution. But after you suggested the parse/stringify solution I decided to go back and watch the video in full and turns out, that will do exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction!